# Equipvalent of VB6's PaintPicture() method in VB.NET?

Tags: .net

As I researched. **Graphics.DrawImage()** can replace **PaintPicture()** when upgrade from VB6 to VB.Net.
However, **DrawImage()** lacks of argument like **Opcode** which defines bit-wise operation.
Please help me to find a correct solution for the replacement.
Thanks.

Comment: We can't help you find a correct solution if you don't tell us what opcode you used.  In the very unlikely case that Graphics.CompositingMode doesn't already get that done then you'll have to pinvoke BitBlt().  This stopped making sense 20 years ago.

Comment: I need to used all available opcode from PaintPicture()...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you have to do it yourself.
**If anyone knows the managed way to do it, please post another answer.**

Create a separate module:

```vb
Module PaintPicture

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Function StretchBlt(ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer, ByVal hSrcDC As IntPtr, ByVal xSrc As Long, ByVal ySrc As Integer, ByVal nSrcWidth As Integer, ByVal nSrcHeight As Integer, ByVal dwRop As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Function SelectObject(ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Function CreateCompatibleDC(ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Function DeleteDC(ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Function DeleteObject(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function


    Private Class DCHandle
        Inherits Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid

        Public Sub New(ByVal hDC As IntPtr)
            MyBase.New(True)

            Me.SetHandle(hDC)
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Function ReleaseHandle() As Boolean
            Return DeleteDC(Me.handle) <> 0
        End Function
    End Class

    Private Class BitmapHandle
        Inherits Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid

        Public Sub New(ByVal hBitmap As IntPtr)
            MyBase.New(True)

            Me.SetHandle(hBitmap)
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Function ReleaseHandle() As Boolean
            Return DeleteObject(Me.handle) <> 0
        End Function
    End Class


    Public Enum Opcodes As Integer
        vbDstInvert = &H550009
        vbMergeCopy = &HC000CA
        vbMergePaint = &HBB0226
        vbNotSrcCopy = &H330008
        vbNotSrcErase = &H1100A6
        vbPatCopy = &HF00021
        vbPatInvert = &H5A0049
        vbPatPaint = &HFB0A09
        vbSrcAnd = &H8800C6
        vbSrcCopy = &HCC0020
        vbSrcErase = &H440328
        vbSrcInvert = &H660046
        vbSrcPaint = &HEE0086
    End Enum


    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub PaintPicture(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal Picture As System.Drawing.Bitmap, ByVal X1 As Integer, ByVal Y1 As Integer, Optional ByVal Width1 As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal Height1 As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal X2 As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal Y2 As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal Width2 As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal Height2 As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal Opcode As Opcodes = Opcodes.vbSrcCopy)

        Dim hDCTarget As IntPtr = g.GetHdc()

        Try
            Using hDCSource = New DCHandle(CreateCompatibleDC(hDCTarget))
                If hDCSource.IsInvalid Then Throw New Exception("Failed to create compatible DC")

                Using hBitmap = New BitmapHandle(Picture.GetHbitmap())
                    Dim prev As IntPtr = SelectObject(hDCSource.DangerousGetHandle(), hBitmap.DangerousGetHandle())

                    Try
                        If prev = IntPtr.Zero Then Throw New Exception("Failed to select bitmap into the compatible DC")

                        If StretchBlt(hDCTarget, X1, Y1, If(Width1 = 0, Picture.Width, Width1), If(Height1 = 0, Picture.Height, Height1), hDCSource.DangerousGetHandle(), X2, Y2, If(Width2 = 0, Picture.Width, Width2), If(Height2 = 0, Picture.Height, Height2), Opcode) = 0 Then
                            Throw New Exception("Failed to draw picture")
                        End If
                    Finally
                        SelectObject(hDCSource.DangerousGetHandle(), prev)
                    End Try

                End Using
            End Using
        Finally
            g.ReleaseHdc(hDCTarget)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

Then use it:

```vb
Using p = New Drawing.Bitmap("picture.jpg")
    Using g = Me.CreateGraphics()

        g.PaintPicture(p, 10, 10, Opcode:=Opcodes.vbSrcInvert)

    End Using
End Using
```